# Deserializing JSON from Controller to AJAX Success

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, json, httpwebrequest

I am having trouble finding the right format of using a `HttpWebRequest`, and returning its response into readable `JSON` for a Javascript AJAX function.

If I return just `text`, it adds escaping slashes to the response. If I deserialize `text` it then add's all the indentation and makes it unreadable by my Javascript. (I think because it is not passing an actual object either)

Just trying to pass a readable json object to my ajax.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult teamLookUp(string ID)
{
    HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("someurl.com/apis");
    myReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
    string text;

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var json2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
    return Json(new { json = json2 });

    // return Json(new {json = text}); returns json with escaping \'s 
    //     i.e. "json":"{\"item":\"item2"}
    // return Json(new {json = json2}); returns empty json, 
    //     i.e. {"json":[[],[],[],[]]}
}
```

**Javascript**

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/Competitive/teamLookUp",
        type: "POST",
        data: "ID=" + ID,
        success: function (json) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(json));
            alert(json[ID].name());
        }, 
        error: function(error) {
        }
   });
```

Need help with returning `json object` back to my AJAX success function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of object are you trying to deserialize the response into?  Right now it is just going into a string.  Might want to create a object to deserialize the response from the service you are calling.

Here is a working example to return a string object I came up with

```
    public ActionResult ReturnJson()
    {
        var someText = "some random text";

        return Json(new {json = someText});
    }
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    function testAjaxCall() {
        $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Action("ReturnJson")',
           type: "POST",
           success: function (result) {
               alert(result);

               alert(result["json"]);
           },
           error: function (error) {}
        });

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
dynamic json2=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
```

instead of

```
var json2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
```

hope that helps

Comment: Can't seem to get `Dynamic` to be recognized as type/namespace. I've tried `System.Dynamic`, and `System.Web.Query.Dynamic`. my targetFramework is 4.5.

Comment: sorry its 'dynamic' not 'Dynamic'